# Can not import requests in python, even then I installed it

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd, python-requests, python-import

I installed "request" but I can not import it in my Python. I dont know why?

CMD:

```
pip install requests
```

Python:

```
import requests
```

[image]

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

[image]

Comment: can you check your virtual environments? my first guess is the venv you installed the package is not the venv you are trying to run the project

Comment: It also could be that you did `pip install` in a Python 2 environment but running the script in Python 3.

Comment: There are too many unknowns. The linked duplicates cover the general cases. You'll have to be a lot more specific to get more specific help.

Comment: @engin_ipek so you mean I need to check that I installed "requests" to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: and for the record I have Python 3 :)

Comment: I fixed that guys, thank you! I have installed requests but it was not in my Python/Scripts . So I installed "requests" in there